# Подскажите, как пишется "хоррор(-)игра" и "хоррор(-)квест"

Tags: орфография, словообразование, заимствования, дефис, слитно-дефис

Как пишутся слова «хоррор(-)игра» и «хоррор(-)квест»? Трудный случай.

Answer (score 4):

1. ***horror*** – ужас, кошмар, страшный, ужасный, жуткий.

Правильно: ***хоррор–игра, хоррор-квест***.

2. ***Хоррор*** обозначено в словаре РАН как самостоятельное слово.
   Орфографический словарь: ***хоррор***, -а и неизм. (триллер). Оно используется и для игр: *хоррор, хорроры, психологический хоррор*.  Практически оно уже стало самостоятельным существительным.
3. Его можно считать приложением или сложным словом с дефисным написанием первой части. Раздельное написание «*хоррор игра*» в русском языке **не нормируется**, хотя встречается.

Но возможна запись «***игры хоррор***» с несогласованным определением в препозиции.